# History of mesoscopic physics

Tags: physics, terminology

Mesoscopic physics is a topic of major research as nanotechnology becomes an important hot topic. There doesn't seem to be a major writing about the history of mesoscopic physics. I know a little about Yoseph Imry and Rofl Landauer.

Are there more important physicists recognized mainly by the work in mesoscopic physics and quantum transport?

I would like to read or find a resume of the important experiments that led to the foundation of the field.

Comment: See the question on Physics SE, [Development/history of Mesoscopic Physics/quantum transport](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92101/development-history-of-mesoscopic-physics-quantum-transport). The answer recommends historical introduction in Nazarov-Blanter's Quantum Transport, Introduction to Nanoscience, [freely available](http://nanophysics.pl/3books/Books/Quantum_Transport.pdf):"*Mesoscopics used to be a very popular term in the 1990s... However, intensive experimental activity in the late 1980s and 1990s did not reveal any sharp border between
meso- and microscales.*"

Comment: Did you even bother to look at the reference list and "related topics" at Wikipedia?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft That is the point. I'm trying to expand Wikipedia's article. It would be nice to add more depth to the field with the name of some physicists and  founding experiments.